# Cannot Check Reaction In Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So basically i was making a modmail system and the problem was we wanted the person who dmed the bot has to react to ✅ if he reacts then the bot has to reply him "OK"
but the code was not working so what is the problem how to fix it?

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  # empty_array = []
  # modmail_channel = discord.utils.get(client.get_all_channels(), name="mod-mail")

  if message.author == client.user:
      return

  if str(message.channel.type) == "private":
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Confirmation',
    color=0x03d692)
    embed.add_field(name="You're sending this message to **The Dynamic Legends**", value="React with :white_check_mark: to confirm." + "\nTo cancel this request, react with :x:.", inline=False)

    confirmation_msg = await message.author.send(embed=embed)

    await confirmation_msg.add_reaction('✅')
    await confirmation_msg.add_reaction('❌')

    sent_users = []
    sent_users.append(message.author.name)
    
    try:
      print('Working')
      
      def check1(reaction, user):
        return user == client.user and user!='Mod Mail Humara#5439' and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'

      reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=30.0, check=check1)

      # print(reaction, user)
      if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
        message.author.send('yes)      

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: What does it currently do? What results are you expecting? Any errors?

Comment: i just want my bot if any person dmes it, it should send a embed with two reaction which it does and after that when the dmed person react to the tick mark emoji then the bot have to send a message to the person 'OK' this is what i want

Comment: what does it currently do?

Comment: it does send the embed

Comment: and we want the bot to reply 'OK' if the person reacts to the tick mark emoji

Comment: Does it add the reactions? Does it print `working`?

Comment: yes it add reactions and it print working

Comment: it cant detect the the person has reacted to the emoji

Comment: Did you add the `except` part? Of you didn't put it in the question?

Comment: yes i put except i forgot to put it in this post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a logic problem in the check func

```py
return user == client.user
```

It simply doesn't make sense, instead of `==` use `!=` and don't put the `user!='Mod Mail Humara#5439'` part

Your check func fixed:

```py
def check1(reaction, user):
    return user != client.user and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'
```

Also `message.author.send` is a coroutine, so you need to await it

```py
await message.author.send("whatever")
```

Your code:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
        embed = discord.Embed(title='Confirmation', color=0x03d692)
        embed.add_field(name="You're sending this message to **The Dynamic Legends**", value="React with :white_check_mark: to confirm." + "\nTo cancel this request, react with :x:.", inline=False)

        confirmation_msg = await message.author.send(embed=embed)

        await confirmation_msg.add_reaction('✅')
        await confirmation_msg.add_reaction('❌')

        sent_users = []
        sent_users.append(message.author.name)

        try:
            def check1(reaction, user):
                return user != client.user and str(reaction.emoji) == '✅'

            reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=30.0, check=check1)

            if str(reaction.emoji) == '✅':
                await message.author.send('yes')
            

        except Exception as e:
            pass
```

Comment: No worries, remember to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: i did everything u said but then also its not replying anything

Comment: That's weird, I edited the answer and wrote the full code, also - what intents have you enabled?

Comment: intents.members = True

Comment: it works flawlessly for me, you’re doing something wrong, did you also enable default ones?

Comment: which default one

Comment: hey if you don't mind can you give me whole code please?

Comment: `intents.default()`, and `intents.members` I can't give you the whole code cause I already did.

Comment: By The Way I Am New To Python Programming And Discord.py

Comment: I know, I can see that

Comment: i didnt enable intents.default

Comment: What intents have you enabled then?

Comment: https://repl.it/@KaranJuneja/Mod-Mail-Bot see this is my bot link can u try to fix it

Comment: You simply didn't pass the intents to the constructor, `client = discord.Client(intents=intents)`

Comment: Ahh Yes I didnt pass the arguments i forgot it , Finally it is working now Thanks Im Accepting Your Answer